# Unable to write code in pydev for django project

Tags: python, django

I am just the beginner in django. I use pydev eclipse in windows 8. First I write a "Hello World " program and display the string in browser but when I changed the code the change in the output is not appear. Whatever I change nothing change in output. But when I close the eclipse and shutdown the computer and restart then I change the program and run it. The code output is changed. But now further to change my program I again need to restart my computer. What is happening ?

Comment: You need to configure pydev/eclipse to autoreload so that when you change files the development server picks up your new changes. See this post for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954603/django-how-to-restart-webserver-so-that-changes-in-sourcecode-get-applied

Comment: I have tried what you have said and follow that link but nothing work properly.Do you have any further idea ?

Comment: Is your setup using Apache or are you using the development server (python manage.py runserver)?  Or are you using something else?

Comment: I think I am using development server. But I don't know how to know the server which I am using.

Comment: have you read the docs ? http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can able to run by using short cut key [ ctrl + shift + F9] or by clicking on button inside blue circle below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to restart development server

Answer (score 0):

You should pass --noreload when you run the program to disable the autoreload (see http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html for details).

Note that if you want to use the autoreload feature, that same page has instructions on how to set things up for it to work.

If you did a launch already, just kill the django-related python process in the task manager so that you can do a new launch properly (otherwise the old one keeps your socket open).